# 'react-bootstrap' does not contain an export named 'Grid'

Tags: reactjs

I tried doing npm start, and receiving the following error.

```
./src/App.js
104:16-24 'react-bootstrap' does not contain an export named 'Grid'.
```

How can I fix this? I tried doing `npm install`. Is there a replacement component?

**Reference Code:**

```
import { PageHeader, Grid, Row, Col, Image } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Comment: Did you try import Grid from "react-bootstrap/Grid";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```sh
$ npm i --save react-bootstrap@0.33
```

I think you have the wrong version of react-bootstrap involved. The Grid component is deprecated in Bootstrap 4+